# Nodemailer with Tutanota Mail in Node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I recently found the e-mail provider [Tutanota](https://tutanota.com), which I found trustworthy and which scored especially high on privacy. However, I cannot manage to run Nodemailer with Tutanota. Does anyone know which host and port Tutanota uses?

Comment: It doesn't look like Tutanota exposes a smtp server for you to use?  As i see it its web interface and a desktop/mobile client. Not sure if you can send email through their api?

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I don't see how I could use their API to send emails from my server

Comment: try using other services like email octopus or postmarkapp.com  they both have an api you can use with your server to send mail thru them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have encountered the same problem as me:
It is not possible to send E-Mails with nodemailer and Tutanota Mail.

I have now switched to [Zoho Mail](https://www.zoho.com/mail/). Sending mails is much easier with Zoho Mail and above all it works.